# How git rebase eliminates previous commits that have been merged onto master?

Tags: git, rebase

In my pull request (to merge branch X onto master) I see commits A, B and C that have already been merged to master.

I have been recommended to rebase the branch force push.

I did `git rebase -i HEAD~3` since the 4th commit is the merging to master. Then I pushed to remote with `--allow-empty`.

In my new PR (to merge X onto master) I still see the old merged commits.

How should I rebase and then push to my branch X?

Thank you!

Comment: "since the 4th commit is the merging to master". Do you mean that your branch starts on top of this commit? Because a commit that is "the merging to master" must **be** on master already. Can you try to illustrate what you had and what you got, after the rebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An illustration, or some `git log --decorate --oneline --graph` output (as plain text), would improve your question.  I've made some assumptions that I think are reasonable here.

You don't normally need to use an interactive rebase and what you wanted was:

```
git fetch                   # make sure origin/* are up to date
git checkout X              # get onto your local branch, if needed
git rebase origin/master    # copy the commits, except for the merge
```

Then your `git push`, assuming your branch X is on `origin` as branch `X` as well, would be:

```
git push --force-with-lease origin X
```

The `--force-with-lease` option is not available in some very old versions of Git; if you have one of those, use plain `-f`, but this bypasses the safety check that `--force-with-lease` provides.